# Using QgsExpression and expression strings for postal address search

Tags: qgis-3

I think this question is more about using QGIS expression strings. I have a large shapefile of postal addresses in an area. And I am trying to write a script where the user inputs an address and the script returns the feature using `QgsFeatureRequest`. In the shapefile is an address field `BEZ` which contains the concatenated full address. This is what I have so far

```
#address to lookup
address_string = address_string.upper()
address_split = address_string.split(' ')
expr = ""

#expression string
for i, add in enumerate(address_split):
    expr += "\"BEZ\" LIKE \'%{}%\'".format(add)            
    if i<len(address_split)-1:
        expr += " AND "

address_ftr = addresses_lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expr)))
```

The expression string works for street name and type, but it doesn't exactly work for the street number. Here are some cases where it doesn't work:

- Looking up "42 Main St" returns "42 Main St" and "142 Main St"
- There are cases where the address is an amalgamated lot so the street number goes like this "142-143 Main St", which would also be returned when you search "42 Main St"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disambiguate the data first

My approach would be to use the field calculator's regex function to split BEZ up into its component parts. Given the time to muck around with it you should be able to cope with all kinds of strange addresses like "Unit 3 45-47 Strait View Rd Southtown" which, in your current routine, would match "3 Strait Rd" and "7 South St" among numerous others.

This would give fields such as unit_number, street_number, street_name, street_type, suburb etc. I'd aim to make street_number numerical so that a value could easily be checked against ranges such as 142-143. An address with a range of street numbers would require two fields: an upper and lower bound with a NULL value in street_number.

Finally, have the user's search address entered with the fields explicitly separated then, with the data in a neat format, it's easier:

1. search for all rows that exactly match street name;
2. among them search for rows that exactly match street type;
3. among them search for rows that exactly match street number;
4. if nothing exactly matches street number search for rows that have a range of street number (NULL in street number) and check if the target falls within any;
5. finally, search for rows with matching unit number.

This routine will be a lot easier to implement if you load the attribute table generated from BEZ into python list objects but that will have performance impacts. With python you could use try-except statements at each of the numbered steps to return partial matches if no exact match can be found.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized I need the address split up into different fields. I know the "BEZ" in the existing shapefile was concatenated from different fields, so the original shapefile should be in our library somewhere. This would simplify the implementation of the expression string by a lot.

I think I'd have a go with your suggestion of separating the search string into different explicit fields. The reason I didn't do this in the first place was because I didn't want to overcrowd the input window because I have other parameters for the next steps after finding the address.